# Satisfying Hypotheses For L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I have that the following hypothesis need to be satisfied in order to use L'Hospital's rule for,
\begin{equation}
   \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
\end{equation}

1. $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have to be functions differentiable near $a$.
2. $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ has to have the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$.
3. $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ has to exist.

If possible, find the following limit using L’Hospital’s rule.  If not possible, explain why,
\begin{equation}
   \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln{x}}{\frac{1}{\sin{x}}}
\end{equation}
How do I check whether the hypothesis are satisfied and whether I can use L’Hospital’s rule for this or not.

I tried differentiating $\ln(x)$ and $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ at $0$ and saw that the derivative of $\ln(x)$ does not exist at $0$. From this, I came to the conclusion that L'Hospital's rule cannot be used. I tried using L'Hospital's anyway and still arrived at the correct answer, $0$, which I verified using Desmos. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The assumptions for L'Hopital's rule do not require the function to be differentiable at $x=a$, but rather on an open interval containing $a$ except possibly at $x=a$. So L'Hopital's rule is valid here.

Comment: Whether the derivative of $\ln (x)$ exists at $0$ is irrelevant. $\lim_{x \to a} \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ can exist when $\lim_{x \to a} f'(x)$ does not.

Comment: You're forgetting another condtion: $g(x)$ has to be nonzero in some small neighbourhood of $a$, except at $a$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

Hypothesis 1 only says that the functions need to be differentiable **near** $a$, not differentiable **at** $a$. Using symbols, they need only be differentiable on some deleted neighbourhood $(a - \delta, a) \cup (a, a + \delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$.

This is similar to what we think of for limits: $\lim_{x \to a} F(x)$ only depends on the behaviour of $F(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$, and doesn't depend on $F(a)$ itself.

Comment: How would I show that ln(x) and sin(x) are differentiable to the right hand side of zero?